# Flutter Bloc Listen to stream and emit state with Cubit

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, state-management, cubit

How can I listen to stream and emit state with `Cubit`?

With `Bloc` we can do something like this:

```
    on<VideoStreamPlayPauseEvent>(
      (event, emit) async {
        if (event.play) {
          await emit.forEach(
            videoStreamingRepo.videoDataStream,
            onData: (VideoData videoStreamData) => VideoStreamState(
              currentFrame: videoStreamData,
              isPlaying: true,
            ),
          );
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should listen to the `stream` using `listen()`
and based on the `event` you can `emit` the desired state.

```
yourstream.listen((event) {
      if (event.play)
          emit(First State)
      else
          emit(Second State)
    });
```

---

##### Extra: Based on the demand of questioner

###### To Stop listening to stream:

```
StreamSubscription<Map<PlaceParam, dynamic>> subscription;
subscription = yourstream.listen((event) {
      if (event.play)
          emit(First State)
      else
          emit(Second State)

      ...
   
      subscription.cancel();  cancel this way
    });
```

Comment: How do I cancel stream?

Comment: You just have to assign it to a variableand cancel it whenever you desire, I have updated my post with an edit . Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

My final result is

```js
enum ConnectionStatus { unknown, connected, disconnected, poor }

class ConnectionCubit extends Cubit<ConnectionStatus> {
  ConnectionCubit() : super(ConnectionStatus.unknown);
  late final StreamSubscription<ConnectivityResult> _streamSubscription;

  void checkConnection() async {
    _streamSubscription = Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((event) {
      if (event == ConnectivityResult.mobile ||
          event == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
        emit(ConnectionStatus.connected);
      } else {
        emit(ConnectionStatus.disconnected);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    _streamSubscription.cancel();
    return super.close();
  }
```